# Save Newlines in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, newline

I just found out that all of the data I've been saving was without any new lines.

I tried searching for solutions here and on google but so far no luck.
I found out that **nl2br()** can swap \n for `<br/>` but it doesn't work for 
me when I take data out of the db and output it.

Right now text from text area is saved and outputted like this:

*eofusethemonitorisalwaysused.AUSBportallowsuserstoback-upshowsthathavebeenrecordedontheJesterTLXtra.AUSBkeyboardcanalsobeconnectedforfastentryofnamesandnumbers.ShowfilesarecompatiblewiththeJesterMLdesks.ADMX-inportallowstheJesterTLXtratobeusedasaback-upconsolef...*

I am also not very good with preg_replace so I messed up there too.

How to save data into mysql with the newlines and breaks?

The preg_replace() I am using for some sanitation:

```
$pattern = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9-.@]/";
```

The main textarea:

```
                                <LABEL CLASS="NORMAL_LABEL" FOR="P_DESC_EN">DESCRIPTION-EN</LABEL>
                            <TEXTAREA ID="P_DESC_EN" NAME="P_DESC_EN" COL="15" ROWS="10"></TEXTAREA>
```

The insert file:

```
    <?php
    $long_desc_en = ($_POST['P_DESC_EN']);
    $pattern = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9-.@]/";
        $clean_long_desc_en = preg_replace($pattern, " ", $long_desc_en);
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO main_table 
        (alpha_p_long_desc_en) VALUES 
        ('$clean_long_desc_en')"); 
        if(!$result)
        {
        echo "Error! ".mysql_error();
        }
?>
```

Thats basically it

Comment: What field type are you storing the data in? text? varchar?

Comment: 3 things missing from this question, the code you use too add the data to the db, the db structure and the code you use to extract and display the data

Comment: The long texts like the one in the example is type text. The shorter ones are type varchar. The table columns are named:

-long_desc_en
-long_desc_mk
-short_desc_en
-short_desc_mk

@Dagon - thanks for the edit, didn't notice the br was actually putting a new line. And my code is irrelevant, hence its not working properly

Comment: lol-if its not an issue with the code, then why are you asking?

Comment: I am asking for a global solution to solve a problem, not a local fix to my code. Here, there is the code. But again, I just needed thoughts on the problem, not the code

Comment: The problem is that your code is wrong.

Comment: Just Bizar - your code is broken do your it fixed or not? Global solution? this is programming not global warming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of errors.

1. Your preg replace says remove anything that's not in that range. Including new line characters.
2. You're not escaping your data pumping into MySQL. Preferably use PDO or mysqli functions, but at a bare minimum use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape the variable.

.

```
<?php 

$long_desc_en = ($_POST['P_DESC_EN']); 
$pattern = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9-.@\n]/"; 
$clean_long_desc_en = mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace($pattern, " ", $long_desc_en)); 
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO main_table (alpha_p_long_desc_en)
                         VALUES ('$clean_long_desc_en')");  
if(!$result) {
    echo "Error! ".mysql_error(); 
} 

?>
```

(But check out PDO; a rought example is below, just add error handling.

```
$clean_long_desc_en = preg_replace($pattern, " ", $long_desc_en); 
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO main_table (alpha_p_long_desc_en)
                         VALUES (:clean_long_desc_en)");  
$sth->bindParam(':clean_long_desc_en', $clean_long_desc_en);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: So how do I add newline characters to the preg_replace?
And the other error is regarding possible sql injection?

Comment: I added \n in the pre_replace. Primarily sql injection, yes, but if you're inserting escaped characters (such as new line) then they'll get unescaped when you insert them. Get's confusing - so just escape string ALWAYS and by default when entring into a DB.

Comment: I've added \n like you said. Then used nl2br() on the output. Works like a charm! Thanks. Just another question - what to put so I can also add break lines, I seem to miss those too. @Dagon - of course it was, I said so myself. The question wasn't about my code, just a question on how to

Comment: @DavidLawDrakulovski of course its about the code, what are you talking about? if its not about the code, why did you have to edit the code to make it work?

Comment: Also just noticed, you have a stray "-" in the preg replace. As that is a special character, you need to escape that as well if you want it in. And you are aware that the ".@" also has a special meaning? If you want those litterally, then add "\" before those too. But adding \n at then end (as you have done) will fix your newline issue.

Comment: Yeah I want the - . @ for emails and addresses. So just make it like this then: "/[^a-zA-Z0-9-/./@\n]/" ? And a break line is a space. @Dagon - because nobody would have bothered to answer me how to preg_replace() new lines without looking at my faulty code. All I asked were solutions on saving new lines to mysql. My code had nothing to do with this :S

Comment: Close - wrong slash. And add a space for a space "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\@\n ]/" If you want all spaces, you can add \s (allow whitespace) which will probably help you a lot.